# How do I concatenate 3 already made vi files to a new file within vi itself for unix?

Tags: unix, vi

I have 3 files made in vi having different texts. How do I concatenate those 3 to a new file from vi?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for https://superuser.com or https://vim.stackexchange.com , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take 2 files --> 1.txt and 2.txt

 Now to see the content of the first file 
  cat 1.txt 
 
a 
 
b 
 
c

cat 2.txt 
 
d 
 
e 
 
f

a) open first file in vi editor. 
 
b) Type :%!paste -2.txt 
 
c) Enter escape and :wq to write and save. 
 
d) file is saved. 
 
e) cat 1.txt to verify.

cat 1.txt 
 
a   d 
 
b   e 
 
c   f

now 1 and 2 are combined, just using vi editor.